# Update variable value without eval again

Tags: variables

Let's say, If I have a directory variable named `a-directory` with its value. Also I have another variable named `b-directory` which gets its value from the previous variable.

```
(setq a-directory "C:/Users/Paper")
(setq b-directory (expand-file-name "org-mode.org" a-directory))
```

Every time when I change the value of `a-directory`, I need to `eval` the `b-directory` again to get its new value. So here comes the question: How can I get the updated value without evaling `b-directory` when changing the value of `a-directory`?

Comment: Please add the missing parenthesis for your code. (And consider getting rid of the backquote and comma.)

Comment: Instead of being a variable, `b-directory` could be a function: `(defun b-directory () (expand-file-name "org-mode.org" a-directory))` - in this case it will evaluate the expression every time (slight overhead), but will be always up to date.

Comment: This is a good idea.

Comment: You could also never change `a-directory` directly through `setq` but from a `change-a-directory` function that would update both `a-directory` and `b-directory`.

Answer (score -1):

Described behavior similar to [reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming), you may found [some](https://github.com/inlinestyle/lifted.el) implementations for elisp.

But I have no experience with them yet. Please, feel free to add usage examples bellow.